# Are flat functors out of a finite category necessarily finite?

Tags: ct.category-theory, model-theory, topos-theory, categorical-logic

**Note**: I've originally asked this question on math stack exchange, but I have learnt that this is the better place to ask for research level questions, so I have deleted the original question there.

---

Let $\mathcal C$ be a finite category. Are all flat functors $\mathcal C \to \mathbf{Set}$ necessarily *finite*, i.e. factors through $\mathbf{FinSet}$?

The reason I am asking this is that, I seem to have a proof that for any finite category $\mathcal C$, its *ind-completion* $\mathrm{Ind}(\mathcal C)$ is equivalent to its *Cauchy completion* $\check{\mathcal C}$, which is finite. The non-trivial part of this is to show $\check{\mathcal C}$ admits all filtered colimits, and it suffices to show it admits all colimits of chains. But since $\check{\mathcal C}$ is finite, for any chain $\kappa \to \check{\mathcal C}$ we can find a cofinal part of it which is constant on some morphism $f$ in $\check{\mathcal C}$; this morphism is necessarily idempotent, thus its splitting should be the colimit of this chain.

If this is true, then by Diaconescu's Theorem we have the following equivalence,
$$ \mathbf{Topos}(\mathbf{Set},[\mathcal C^{op},\mathbf{Set}]) \simeq \mathrm{Flat}(\mathcal C,\mathbf{Set}) \simeq \mathrm{Ind}(\mathcal C^{op}) \simeq \check{\mathcal C^{op}}, $$
which implies the category of flat functors out of $\mathcal C$ is finite. Now we can indeed explicitly write down a coherent theory $T_{\mathcal C}$ of flat functors out of $\mathcal C$. Since $\mathcal C$ is finite, $T_{\mathcal C}$ is given by finitely many non-logical symbols and axioms. Hence by Löwenheim–Skolem theorem, if $T_{\mathcal C}$ has an infinite model, then it has models of all cardinality, which in particular implies $\mathrm{Mod}(T_{\mathcal C})$ cannot be a finite category. Thus, this seems to have proved that all flat functors out of $\mathcal C$ must be finite.

However, I fail to see this from a more direct approach. Is there a more simple and direct argument showing flat functors out of a finite category $\mathcal C$ can basically only be retracts of corepresentables? The closet result I can find in the literature is the following statement in [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022404999001905) which works for all categories:

> **Corollary 3.8**: Finitely presented flat functors are retracts of representable functors.

Comment: An early reference for the statement you mention is SGA4(2), Exposé VI, Exercice 3.12(b). But it is presented as part of a series of exercises, without writing down a full proof.

Comment: @JensHemelaer Thanks for this reference as well! I will have a look :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A positive answer to your first question can be seen as a consequence of Lemma 2.5 of [On continuity of accessible functors](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10485-022-09677-x).
Following the notation of the Lemma, you should take $\beta$ to be the maximum between the the number of objects and the number of morphisms of your $\mathcal C$, and $\gamma=\aleph_0$. Then a $\gamma$-flat functor is simply a flat functor; while $\mathbf{Set}_\beta$ is the category of sets with less than $\beta$ elements, which is contained in $\mathbf{FinSet}$ since $\beta$ is finite.

Then, the fact that $Ind(\mathcal C)$ coincides with tha Cauchy completion of $\mathcal C$ is a consequence of 2.6 and 2.8 of the same paper.

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer and the reference, this is exactly I was looking for!